# WIX and preconditions (DLLs/OCXs in System32, ...)

Tags: wix, wix3.6

*What i have:*
I have an installations routine written in WIX 3.6 (with heat, candle, light)

*What's the problem:*
it only installs the app-folder-files (registering activex-components, registering and starting a service, making regentries, ...) and not DLLs/OCXs in the System32-folder. also the avalabiliy of ADO (ActiveX Data Objects) isn't checked.

Which is the best way to deal this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If there are files you created that need installed to
  System32, then you need to manually edit your .wxs file(s) to include
  those files.
- If you have third party prerequisites that need installed, generally speaking you would install them using the distribution method (installer) provided by the vendor. You can then [create a WiX bundle](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/authoring_bundle_intro.htm) that installs your prerequisites before installing your package.